# Disable logging PHP Notices into php.log file (php.ini)

Tags: php, configuration-files, error-reporting, php-ini

I have a situation on my server, my log files are taking up too much space and I see that there are a lot of warnings that are being logged. I would want to disable notices logging for now and keep the disk space under check.

The change I added onto php.ini file was:

```
error_reporting = E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR
```

I restarted my apache and zend but I still see that notices are still being logged into the php.log file.

Please let me know if there is something else that I need to configure.

Comment: do you solve your problem?

Comment: Why not fix the notices?

Comment: @ceejayoz Why clean up when you can just hide the mess under the carpet?

Comment: @ceejayoz: We do not have resources to fix it and we have decided to just hide to errors since server space is a luxury we do not want to give up on logs. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Report all errors except E_NOTICE
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE)
```

You can read more at:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php